# Graphics of Ebbinghaus illusion

Tags: plotting, graphics

I define two graphics for
  [Ebbinghaus illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebbinghaus_illusion)

```
color = RGBColor[0.5686314191548986`, 0.6431257328883857`, 0.7255014941881315`] 
color2 = RGBColor[0.9019616959261525, 0.49803803022437004,0.2235295987167626]

g1 = Graphics[{color2, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5], color, Disk[{2.1, 0}, 1], 
color, Disk[{2.1 Sin[Pi/6], 2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1], color, 
Disk[{-2.1, 0}, 1], color, 
Disk[{-2.1 Sin[Pi/6], 2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1], color, 
Disk[{2.1 Sin[Pi/6], -2.1  Cos[Pi/6]}, 1], color, 
Disk[{-2.1 Sin[Pi/6], -2.1  Cos[Pi/6]}, 1]}]
```

and

```
g2=Graphics[{color2, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5], color, 
Disk[{ Sin[Pi/4], Cos[Pi/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{ Sin[2 Pi/4], Cos[(2 Pi)/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{ Sin[3 Pi/4], Cos[3 Pi/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{ Sin[4 Pi/4], Cos[4 Pi/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{ Sin[(5 Pi)/4], Cos[(5 Pi)/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{ Sin[6 Pi/4], Cos[(6 Pi)/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{ Sin[7 Pi/4], Cos[(7 Pi)/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{ Sin[8 Pi/4], Cos[(8 Pi)/4]}, 0.3]}]
```

how to plot it side by side like the original [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bc/Mond-vergleich.svg)

[image]

I tried:

```
GraphicsGrid[g1, g2]
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: You just have the wrong [syntax for `Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html), which always takes an array. Try `GraphicsRow[{g1, g2}]` or `GraphicsGrid[{{g1, g2}}]`.

Comment: @MarcoB ok. but size of centered spheres is not [same](http://i.imgur.com/eKBJeEz.png)

Comment: Use `Show[g1, Translate[#, {5, 0}] & /@ g2]` to put them side by side. Working only with `Graphics` is the best way to ensure that the coordinate system is preserved, that no resizing is happening etc.

Comment: @vito just add `ImageSize` to your `g1` and `g2` and it should work

Comment: @C.E. thanks. it works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create your graphics illusion with a single `Graphics` expression; like so

```
With[
   {color1 = RGBColor[0.569, 0.643, 0.725],
    color2 = RGBColor[0.902, 0.498, 0.224]},
 Module[{group1, group2},
   group1 =
     {color2, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5],
      color1, Disk[{2.1, 0}, 1],
      Disk[{2.1 Sin[Pi/6], 2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1],
      Disk[{-2.1, 0}, 1],
      Disk[{-2.1 Sin[Pi/6], 2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1],
      Disk[{2.1 Sin[Pi/6], -2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1],
      Disk[{-2.1 Sin[Pi/6], -2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1]};
   group2 =
     {color2, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5],
      color, Disk[{Sin[Pi/4], Cos[Pi/4]}, 0.3],
      Disk[{Sin[2 Pi/4], Cos[(2 Pi)/4]}, 0.3],
      Disk[{Sin[3 Pi/4], Cos[3 Pi/4]}, 0.3],
      Disk[{Sin[4 Pi/4], Cos[4 Pi/4]}, 0.3],
      Disk[{Sin[(5 Pi)/4], Cos[(5 Pi)/4]}, 0.3],
      Disk[{Sin[6 Pi/4], Cos[(6 Pi)/4]}, 0.3],
      Disk[{Sin[7 Pi/4], Cos[(7 Pi)/4]}, 0.3],
      Disk[{Sin[8 Pi/4], Cos[(8 Pi)/4]}, 0.3]};
   Graphics[{group1, Translate[group2, {5, 0}]}]]]
```

[image]

This guarantees that both groups of disks are created in the a single coordinate system.

With Mathematica V10.1 or later this can simplified by using `CirclePoints` to place the outer ring of circles.

```
With[
    {color1 = RGBColor[0.569, 0.643, 0.725],
     color2 = RGBColor[0.902, 0.498, 0.224],
     offset = {5, 0},
     r = .5, r1 = 1., r2 = .3, R1 = 2.1, R2 = .9},
  Module[{group1, group2},
    group1 =
     {color2, Disk[{0, 0}, r],
      color1, Disk[#, r1] & /@ CirclePoints[R1, 6]};
    group2 =
      {color2, Disk[offset, r],
       color1, Disk[#, r2] & /@ CirclePoints[offset, {R2, 0}, 8]};
    Graphics[{group1, group2}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Example

**Code**

```
color = RGBColor[0.5686314191548986`, 0.6431257328883857`, 
  0.7255014941881315`]
color2 = RGBColor[0.9019616959261525, 0.49803803022437004, 
  0.2235295987167626]

g1 = Graphics[{color2, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5], color, Disk[{2.1, 0}, 1], 
   color, Disk[{2.1 Sin[Pi/6], 2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1], color, 
   Disk[{-2.1, 0}, 1], color, 
   Disk[{-2.1 Sin[Pi/6], 2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1], color, 
   Disk[{2.1 Sin[Pi/6], -2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1], color, 
   Disk[{-2.1 Sin[Pi/6], -2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 200]

g2 = Graphics[{color2, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5], color, 
   Disk[{Sin[Pi/4], Cos[Pi/4]}, 0.3], color, 
   Disk[{Sin[2 Pi/4], Cos[(2 Pi)/4]}, 0.3], color, 
   Disk[{Sin[3 Pi/4], Cos[3 Pi/4]}, 0.3], color, 
   Disk[{Sin[4 Pi/4], Cos[4 Pi/4]}, 0.3], color, 
   Disk[{Sin[(5 Pi)/4], Cos[(5 Pi)/4]}, 0.3], color, 
   Disk[{Sin[6 Pi/4], Cos[(6 Pi)/4]}, 0.3], color, 
   Disk[{Sin[7 Pi/4], Cos[(7 Pi)/4]}, 0.3], color, 
   Disk[{Sin[8 Pi/4], Cos[(8 Pi)/4]}, 0.3]}, ImageSize -> 100]

GraphicsRow[{g1,g2}]
```

**Output**

[image: output]

**Reference**

[GraphicsRow](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsRow.html)
[ImageSize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html)

Comment: Worth to mention `CirclePoints` for V10+.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic  why exactly `ImageSize->100` and not  `ImageSize->101` ? :)  centered spheres is not same size  in your graphic

Comment: @vito I just used arbitrary numbers, feel free to manipulate these as you find appropriate

Answer (score 2):

I used code from C.E comment, and it works perfectly!

```
color = RGBColor[0.5686314191548986`, 0.6431257328883857`,0.7255014941881315`]
color2 = RGBColor[0.9019616959261525, 0.49803803022437004,0.2235295987167626]

g1 = Graphics[{color2, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5], color, Disk[{2.1, 0}, 1], 
color, Disk[{2.1 Sin[Pi/6], 2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1], color, 
Disk[{-2.1, 0}, 1], color, 
Disk[{-2.1 Sin[Pi/6], 2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1], color, 
Disk[{2.1 Sin[Pi/6], -2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1], color, 
Disk[{-2.1 Sin[Pi/6], -2.1 Cos[Pi/6]}, 1]}]

g2 = Graphics[{color2, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5], color, 
Disk[{Sin[Pi/4], Cos[Pi/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{Sin[2 Pi/4], Cos[(2 Pi)/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{Sin[3 Pi/4], Cos[3 Pi/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{Sin[4 Pi/4], Cos[4 Pi/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{Sin[(5 Pi)/4], Cos[(5 Pi)/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{Sin[6 Pi/4], Cos[(6 Pi)/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{Sin[7 Pi/4], Cos[(7 Pi)/4]}, 0.3], color, 
Disk[{Sin[8 Pi/4], Cos[(8 Pi)/4]}, 0.3]}]

Show[g1, Translate[#, {5, 0}] & /@ g2]
```

[image]